# How to dynamically load module from server using React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-router

I have a React / Typescript / Webpack / React-Router app that includes some fairly large JS modules.  I currently include 2 bundles (common.js and app.js) on every page.  common.js is a CommonsChunkPlugin bundle.

However, there is a fair amount code in common.js that is only necessary on very few pages of the site, and I do not want to load from the server, or import them, them unless they are necessary.  I am fine with specifying exactly which pages need these libraries.

I have successfully split the "big" libraries out into their own bundle (big.js) using webpack, but I do not know how to conditionally include it so that it only loads when I request it.   Seems like I have to conditionally include it in React somehow?

How do I dynamically include a webpack JS bundle only on certain React components?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Dynamic Imports With Webpack 2](https://dev.to/kayis/dynamic-imports-with-webpack-2)?

Comment: Looks like this is the right direction, but can you fill it out more with the relevant details on how this could be used?

Comment: @Doug this might be what you are looking for in a React-context: https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable

Comment: Yes this is it.  There are some gotchas though, like you need to set module: 'esnext' instead of 'commonjs'